# How can i hide the form1 ? I want that the icon of the form only will be show in the taskbar in the bottom

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Visible = false;
}
```

Didn't work so I tried `this.Hide();`, also didn't work.
What am I missing ?

Comment: You're putting your code in the form's constructor... try the `Load` or `Activated` event handler.

Comment: Tried now in the Load event didn't work either.

Comment: Solution i guess is: this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; in the Load event. It's not hide but it's good enough.

Comment: Are you really looking for an icon to be in the TASKBAR without a corresponding form?  I think maybe you're looking for an icon in the SYSTEM TRAY (down by the clock) instead.  If so, look at using the NotifyIcon() control.

Comment: Just try with opacity

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `SetVisibleCore` method:

```
bool initHidden;
protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value){
   if(!initHidden) {
       base.SetVisibleCore(false);
       initHidden = true;
   } else base.SetVisibleCore(value);
}
```

If you want to hide your form **in the whole life circle**, just do this:

```
protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `Opacity` as 0

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Opacity = 0;
    }
```